# UWP:- GraphicsCaptureAccess.RequestAccessAsync(GraphicsCaptureAccessKind.Borderless) throws exception

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm trying to have a borderless screen capture by updating by project target version to windows 10 SDK 20348. I updated the package manifest to include graphicsCaptureWithoutBorder capability like below

```
    <Package   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10" xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest"   xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10"   xmlns:uap6="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/6" xmlns:uap11="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/11" IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp uap6 uap11">
    
      <Capabilities>
        <Capability Name="internetClient" />
        <uap6:Capability Name="graphicsCapture"/>
        <uap11:Capability Name="graphicsCaptureWithoutBorder"/>    
</Capabilities> 
</Package>
```

and adding the following code to request consent to disable border,

```
           Direct3D11CaptureFramePool _framePool = Direct3D11CaptureFramePool.CreateFreeThreaded(
                    _canvasDevice, // D3DDevice
                    DirectXPixelFormat.B8G8R8A8UIntNormalized,
                    2, 
                    _captureItem.Size);
           GraphicCaptureSession _session = _framePool.CreateCaptureSession(_captureItem);
            AppCapabilityAccessStatus appCapabilityAccessStatus = await GraphicsCaptureAccess.RequestAccessAsync(GraphicsCaptureAccessKind.Borderless);
            if (appCapabilityAccessStatus == AppCapabilityAccessStatus.Allowed)
            {
                _session.IsBorderRequired = false;
            }
```

However, upon invoking RequestAccessAsync method, the following exception (in the attached image occurs),

I'm I missing something?

[image]

Comment: What's your os version? Does the exception throw this line `GraphicCaptureSession _session = _framePool.CreateCaptureSession(_captureItem);`

Comment: Os version is 10.0.19042 Build 19042 and exception is thrown when I call GraphicCaptureAccess.RequestAccessAsync. It doesn’t throw on create capture session

Comment: I'm I missing something from my side. Any updates on this @NicoZhu-MSFT?

Comment: Not yet, I have reported this problem, I will comment below if I have info.

Comment: Sorry guy, I leaved msft for long time, you may need to ask roy-msft for help!